# Hot Questions in iOS Notification Center not working

Tags: bug, ios-app, hot-questions

I really like the Hot Questions widget, because it's interesting to see.

However, today I got an update. When I clicked on it, it would not open the app. I then removed it and added back into NC. It stopped showing questions completely! It still does this.

Then, I got another update just now before posting this question. It still does not work.

Please fix this!

I am on an iPad using 8.1.3. I am also on the beta version.

Comment: Hi, whoever down voted my question, why?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something or I'm just dumb - how do I turn this widget on?

Comment: @NateBarbettini Go to the notification center, click Edit, and from there it's mostly self explanatory. Most apps updated for iOS 8 support might have a widget, like Dropbox or Yahoo Weather.

Comment: Cool! I actually didn't know about that feature in iOS 8. FWIW, clicking on a question in the widget correctly opens the app for me, on an iPhone 6 w/ iOS 8.1.

Comment: @NateBarbettini It may be because I have the beta version, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Might be relevant. ;) I'm not sure why there isn't an `ios-beta` tag, or the like.

Comment: I can't reproduce it here using the beta app on ios8.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I'll add a screenshot. I can still reproduce it here right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It now works. Interesting. Amazing what a reboot does.