# Only successful question posts should count towards rate limit

Tags: bug, ios-app, rate-limiting

On my last question, I missed off [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), so my question was rejected. I went back and added the tag, hit submit, and was then told I couldn't post another question for another 46 seconds.

Additionally, the failed question was then saved as a draft, even though I posted it as soon as I was able to, without ever leaving the question-posting interface.

App v1.2.2.189.

Comment: It's also briefly mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248495/usability-roadblocks-submitting-bug-reports-in-the-android-app), though OP there calls it "penalty delay" or "time penalty". Since it's also related to  the API, guess fixing this in the API would fix it for both apps.

Comment: Hey why did you delete [this other question of yours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248591/hot-questions-widget-gets-cut-off-with-no-connection)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Because I couldn't reproduce it, and because of this question below, I thought maybe it was just temporarily a bit buggy with one update. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248131/233816

Comment: Hmm... weird. Well, keep an eye over this and worst case guess you can always undelete that other report. :)